# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/**.mp4" on emulator

Tags: android

> Android Emulator
>  Android version 9
>  API level 28

```
final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
Log.i(TAG,"DocumentId:"+id);
String id2=id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
Log.i(TAG,"id2:"+id2);
long appendId=Long.valueOf(id2);
final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), appendId);
return getDataColumn(this, contentUri, null, null);
```

the log message is:

> I/MainActivity:
> DocumentId:raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4
> I/MainActivity: id2:/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4

error log message is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.demo.videotrimmer/com.demo.videotrimmer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4"
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:583)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:808)
    at com.demo.videotrimmer.MainActivity.getPath(MainActivity.java:151)
    at com.demo.videotrimmer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score -1):

As your print log shows, value of id2 is a string, so you can't convert it into long.

I/MainActivity: id2:/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4

But you are trying to convert it into a Long.

```
Long.valueOf(id2);
```

That's why NumberFormatException occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple. You are trying to convert string to long which contains alphabets. To covert from string to Long or int, its all characters must be digits else NumberFormateException will occured.

To avoid this exception try to implement a check which will check that your string contains digits only.

```
if (text.matches("[0-9]+") && text.length() > 2) {
// do your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[**Long#valueOf**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) can only parse a string made up of decimal numbers.

```java
//...
String id2=id.replaceFirst("raw:", ""); //"/storage/emulated/0/Download/SD20210615_141921.mp4"
Log.i(TAG,"id2:"+id2);
String myId = id2.replaceFirst(".*_([0-9]+).*$", "$1"); //For 141921
//String myId = id2.replaceFirst(".*/[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*$", "$1"); //For 20210615
long appendId = Long.valueOf(myId);
//...
```